# Reformat Menu Bar CSS Design

Tags: css

Hi I am reformatting a menu bar in CSS design using Sublime text reader. This is for a homepage created from a template using Omeka. The main problem I am having is the padding on the end of the menu-bar; particularly with the "last-child". I tried to add padding to see if that would expand the background color but it won't change. The background color ends directly after the word ends. Here is the code:

```css
#primary-nav
{
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;    
}
#primary-nav a
{
    display: block;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #13294B;
    text-align: center;
    height: 53px;
    line-height: 53px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
#primary-nav li
{
    border: none;
}
#primary-nav li a:hover
{
    background-color: #00a3e0;
    color: #121111;
}
#primary-nav .navigation > li:first-child a
{
    border: none;
}
#primary-nav .navigation > li:last-child a
{
    border:none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

As a last note, if there is a way to condense this code that would be nice. This is the code that was generated from the template. The only part that was added was "last-child" to fix the formatting at the end of the menu bar.

Here is a link to the webpage so you can see what I am describing. http://digitalhistory.butlerlibraryservices.org/

Answer (score 2):

You have this line in your `style.css` CSS file (Line 1931) which is causing the problem:

```
#primary-nav .navigation > li:last-child a {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Remove it and you should fix your issue.